# Scanf not working in while loop when nonmatching string is entered

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using a function called **checkType** to check whether the user has entered a valid input of integer type. For example, if the user enters 15 it will print **valid** and 15c will print **not valid**. However, if the user enters a string input only like **ccccc**, it results in an infinite loop and the program crashes. I have added some screenshots below to show the outputs.

```
int checkType(int input, char *c) {
  if (input == 2 and *c == '\n') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  };
}

int main(void) {
  int faces = 0;
  char c;
  int valid = 0;
  int input;

  while (valid == 0) {
    printf("Enter number of faces: ");
    input = scanf("%d%c", &faces, &c);
    valid = checkType(input, &c);
    printf(valid == 0 ? "not valid\n" : "valid\n");
  }
}
```

[image]

**Infinite Loop:**

[image]

Comment: If anything here is actually C++ I missed it.

Comment: Read this and report whether you still have problems please: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: There's no `and` in C, use `&&`.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour.  Since `scanf()` leaves the character that can't be converted in the input, it will repeatedly fail to convert.  You have to recover somehow.  For example, you could read the failing character and continue.  Or you could read to end of line.  Or you could terminate the loop on failure.  Or you could read lines with `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`), and then process the result with `sscanf()`.  Your choice.

Comment: @Shadowchaser: check [`<iso646.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.9) — there is occasionally an `and` in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `scanf()` family of functions is not really made for input of questionable syntax.

The usual approach to solve your problem is to read in all the input in a way which is sure to succeed, e.g. by reading a complete line (instead of a number, word-like string, or anything else with expected format) with `fgets()`.
Then you can try to parse that line-representing string as by expected format. (You can use `sscanf()` for the parsing attempt.) If that fails you ignore it and read the next line, or try parsing according to an alternative allowed format for the same input.

The relevant difference is that reading a whole line will succeed and remove it from the input stream. In contrast to that, your code, in case of syntax failure, leaves in the input stream whatever did not match the expected syntax. As such it will, of course, fail the next iteration of the reading loop again. That is what causes your endless loop.

In detail:

- read a whole line into a buffer,
  using `fgets()` and the option to restrict the number of characters to the size of the buffer
- at this point all of the line is removed from the input (aka stdin, aka input stream),
  which means that the next read will get new input even if the read line does not match any allowed format,
  this is the relevant difference to trying to read input directly with `scanf()`
- from the line buffer, attempt to read separate values according to an allowed format,
  using `sscanf()` and with a check of the return value
- if successful great, you have your expected variables filled (e.g. an integer);
  you could try scanning for additional, not format-covered trailing input (and continue like for incorrect input, even if the beginning of the line matched an allowed format)
- if not successful try a different allowed format,
  using `sscanf()` again,
  from the same line buffer, which is not changed, not even if a format partially matched
- if no allowed format matches the input it is time to consider it incorrect
- incorrect input can be ignored or can cause a fatal parsing error in your program, your choice

Comment: I thought fgets is used only when you are trying to read a line from a file. correct me if I'm wrong or maybe give me an example cause I'm new to C.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is used for. You read the whole line into a buffer. Then you can try multiple allowed formats on that line. If no allowed format succeeds to cover the whole line you ingore it (or complain by outputting an errors message and abort processing) and read the next line. I think that is what I wrote. Can I rephrase something to make my answer clearer or otherwise more helpful?

Comment: fgets expects a string. I had to convert the results to an integer.

Comment: I added step-by-step. I think it covers when and how you get your integer variable filled after first reading all the line as text into a buffer.

Answer (score 3):

> However, if the user enters a string input only like ccccc,
> it results in an infinite loop and the program crashes

Reason : `scanf` returns the number of valid read values from `stdin`. If we give `cccc` as input,  `scanf` cannot read the value, because the input and variable `faces` are of different data type. This makes `input = 0`. So the function `checkType` returns 0, which in turn makes `valid = 0`. This makes `while(valid == 0)` always true and hence the endless loop.

Comment: Use the method suggested by  Yunnosch to prevent this

Answer (score 2):

Scanf will read form stdin, and not clean the stdin buffer if not match. So it will read wrong data again in your case, you can just add a clean function with stdin after scanf, like: `__fpurge(stdin)`

You can refer to the following two links:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: Note that `__fpurge()` is not part of the standard C library.

Comment: Yes, but this is the only function available on my machine, fflush() does not work and fpurge() fails to build.

Answer (score 0):

With input like `"ccccc"` and `scanf("%d%c" ...`, there is no conversion to an `int`.  `scanf()` returns 0 **and `stdin` remains unchanged**.  Calling the function again has the same result.

Code neds to consume errant input - somehow.

Research `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input.

Comment: Um, is there anything in this which is not already covered by one of the other answers? I mean, even if you ignore mine... I seem to miss the point of this post by a user which I kind of respect, not to say admire... @chux