# Reading multiple input types from console in C

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

I want to have either an integer or a string in C.
I thought about `scanf(("%d, &first) || ("%s", second));` with `int first` and `char second[20]`, but I am not sure if that's the way to go- do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read as a string (preferably read the whole line) then try to convert it to an integer. If the conversion fails then it's not a number.

Comment: How would that work if the first parameter is an IP Address?

Comment: The [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) funciton have validation built in, and also allows you to check if all of the string was converted or not. So to add to my previous comment: If the conversion fails *or not all of the string was converted* then it's not a number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanf not working in while loop when nonmatching string is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870792/scanf-not-working-in-while-loop-when-nonmatching-string-is-entered)

Comment: ... indirectly I mean. The question is different, but the accepted answer (admittedly mine) describes a method which also covers what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

A Simple solution would be

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long num  = 0;
    char str[40];
    char *end = NULL;  // pointer to end char
    
    printf("Enter string or number : ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin); // works for string with space too
    
    num = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    
    if(*end != '\n') // last character is newline which not removed by fgets
    {
        printf("You Entered String is %s", str);
    }
    else if(end > str)
    {
        printf("you Entered Number is %ld", num);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Nothing");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost correct: you should also check that `end > str`, otherwise an empty line will be interpreted as a number.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :-), I can't understand what you mean by empty line could you please elaborate or could you please give sample input ?. I think you mean empty line is "" but fgets atleast contain '\n'.

Comment: Enter string or number : 123456789123456789012334                                                 
you Entered Number is 9223372036854

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan  If the input is greater than LONG_MAX, code gives us correct output (number not string), but the number printed is wrong

Comment: `fgets()` will store a newline and a null byte into `str` for an empty line. `strtol()` will return `0` and set `end = str` for this line, which your code will interpret as a number because `*end == '\n'`.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Thanks for your suggestion, we can't store value in long greater than LONG_MAX, its a overflow, init and check errno with strerror().

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for yout explanation i have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf()` for your purpose and check its return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int first;
    char second[20];

    if (scanf("%d", &first) == 1) {
        printf("you typed an integer value: %d\n", first);
    } else
    if (scanf("%19s", second) == 1) {
        printf("you typed a word: %s\n", second);
    } else {
        printf("input error\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that `92.34.12.34` will be handled by `scanf()` as an integer `92` followed by other characters `.34.12.34`, left in `stdin` for the next input operation, which might not be your intent. Reading one full line at a time with `fgets()` allows for more accurate input validation.

Comment: For an IP addrees as input, your code output is : **`92.34.12.34 (input)
you typed an integer value: 192` (output**).   Your code considers IP address a number. Please check

Comment: Indeed, it does and I documented this in the paragraph below the code.

Comment: Code fails for IP address as input. So I made chages to include this particular test case.

Comment: My goal is for the OP to realise the shortcomings of `scanf()` for input validation.

Comment: And included `.` to take care of IP addresss as input (test case)

Comment: OP mentioned this in comments  **"How would that work if the first parameter is an IP Address?"**

Answer (score 0):

Get entered text as String then recognize that is Int or String

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi
#include <ctype.h> // isdigit

int IsNumber(const char* text){
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(text); i++){
        // isdigit returns a non-zero value if it’s a digit else it returns 0
        if(isdigit(text[i]) == 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(){
    char Buffer[256];
    scanf("%s", Buffer);
    
    if(IsNumber(Buffer)){

        int Number = atoi(Buffer);
        printf("entered text is Integer: %d\n", Number);
        
    } else {

        printf("entered text is String: %s\n", Buffer);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only numbers or string, change matching string to `0123456789` (second argument of `strspn()`) . If you want to check for additional characters, just add those characters to the second argument of `strspn()`.

For example, if you want to check for IP address, which consists of `.`, add `.(dot)` to the string (second argument of `strspn()`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void isNumberOrString(char* str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    if(len == 0)
    {
       printf("Empty\n");
       return;
    }

    int len2 = strspn(str, ".0123456789"); // scans str and return the number of characters that match characters in the string (.0123456789)
    
    
if(len == len2)
{
    if(strchr(str, '.') == NULL)
    {
        printf("Numbers\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Numbers with dots \n");
    }
    
}
    else
    printf("A string\n");
    
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "192.168.43.8" ;
    char str2[] = "123454612343" ;
    char str3[] = "Hello World";

    isNumberOrString(str);
    isNumberOrString(str2);
    isNumberOrString(str3);
    return 0;
}
```

We can use [strspn()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) function. It will return the number of characters, that match the input string. If the total length of the string is equal to the length returned by `strpsn` then it is a number. I added `. (dot)` to include IP address as well.

The output is for three test cases:

```
Numbers with dots 
Numbers
A string
```

Please see the link for more information about `strspn()` :[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strspn-function-c/#:~:text=The%20strspn()%20function%20returns,str1%20%3A%20string%20to%20be%20scanned](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strspn-function-c/#:%7E:text=The%20strspn()%20function%20returns,str1%20%3A%20string%20to%20be%20scanned).

Comment: What about negative integer (e.g. -1) as input ?

Comment: @gobinda  if input string is `"-123"`, then we just have to add `- (minus)`  to `.-0123456789` (matching string part)

Comment: Your approach is incorrect: `"192.168.43.8"` will be recognised as a number, but it is not a number. Just checking the characters is not enough: `..` is not a number either. Use `strtol()` or `strtod()` to tray and match the number syntaxes.

Comment: @chqrlie  IP address is not number. But the user mentioned (in comments), that his input can be IP address. So to include that case, I added `. (dot)`

Comment: @chqrlie  If the input is IP address, `strtol()` fails. And if the number entered is more than `LONG_MAX` then also `strtol()` fails

Comment: @chqrlie  Statement is **`Number and may include . dot`** , and I never mentioned IP address as a number. Please check the code.

Comment: The statement **Number and may include . dot** is unambiguous: it implies the string is a number... The IP address does contain a number but it is not a number, and neither `.` nor `..` are numbers, hence your approach is not sufficient. (I am sorry to say this because it is a rare occasion where `strspn()` is put to good use :)

Comment: @chqrlie Pleae understand, why I included `.` . Please see the comments, where the user mentioned , his input can be IP address.

Comment: I understand, but you should use a more precise validation for IP addresses: `if (sscanf("%u.%u.%u.%u", &ip1, &ip2, &ip3, &ip4) == 4 && (ip1 | ip2 | ip3 | ip4) <= 255)` an even this is not enough: `scanf()` will still accept extra spaces and `+` signs. Accurate input validation is difficult.