# C- How to restrict user to only enter a specific amount of elements?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, element

I want the user to enter 10 numbers, and if they enter anything else but 10 numbers I want to tell them it's invalid. Not quite sure how to do it, I tried with an if-statement like this:

```
{
    char numbers[11];
    printf("Enter your 10 numbers: ");
    scanf("%s", numbers);

    if ( *numbers != 11)
        printf("Enter a valid number.\n");
    else
        printf("Your number is %s: \n", numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `scanf("%10s", numbers)` - but they aren't numbers. You'll read one string of max 10 characters.

Comment: `*numbers != 11` is the same as `numbers[0] == 11`. Which checks if the first character value of the `numbers` array is equal to the integer `11`. And that will only be true if the first character in the string is a vertical tab (using ASCII encoding).

Comment: Perhaps you really want to check if the length of the string is equal to `10` instead? Like `strlen(numbers) == 10`? But that will only check if the string have exactly ten *characters*, it could be any characters (letters, spaces, digits, punctuation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanf not working in while loop when nonmatching string is entered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870792/scanf-not-working-in-while-loop-when-nonmatching-string-is-entered)

Comment: Do you want the user to enter ten digits (like “1234566600”) or ten numbers (like “34 17 -82.3 95 2 1 1 1 1 1”? If the former, use a loop to read ten characters, and report an error if any of them is not a digit. Whether an error occurred, to finish reading the line the user entered, read more characters until there is a new-line character (possibly also reporting an error if non-digit and non-space characters are found). Also, if an error or end-of-file occurs during any of those reads, stop and report a problem.

Comment: If you want to read ten numbers, use a loop to read ten numbers, possibly using `scanf` with `%d` and an `int`, and report an error if any read of a number fails. Continue as above to finish reading the line the user entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restrict the read string to max 10 `char`s (with `%10s`) - or else you risk writing out of bounds.
You should also make sure that reading works and you can count the number of `char`s in the string with `strlen`.

`numbers` is misleading here though. It'll accept any non whitespace `char`s.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers[11];
    printf("Enter your 10 numbers: ");
    if(scanf("%10s", numbers) != 1 || strlen(numbers) != 10) {
        printf("Enter a valid number.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Your number is: %s\n", numbers);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to make sure that the entered string only contains digits, you could restrict the `scanf` format to `%10[0-9]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char numbers[11];
    printf("Enter your 10 digits: ");
    if(scanf("%10[0-9]", numbers) != 1 || strlen(numbers) != 10 ) {
        printf("Enter a valid number.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Your number is: %s\n", numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution won't check if the entered characters are really numerical digits. It'll work even if you enter 10 random characters

Comment: @Fractal Now it will :-)